# Python SQLAlchemy: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Using Python: when connecting to SQL Server using pyodbc, everything works fine, but when I switch to sqlalchemy, the connection fails, giving me the error message:

```
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

My code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password')
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@servername/dbname")
```

I can't find the error in my code, and don't understand why the first options works, but the second doesn't.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works using pymssql, instead of pyodbc.

Install pymssql using pip, then change your code to:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://username:password@servername/dbname")
```

Comment: Pymssql is discontinued: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668

Comment: thanks, I was searching for 2 days just this worked for me,

Answer (score 44):

Ran into this problem as well, appending a driver query string to the end of my connection path worked:

```
"mssql+pyodbc://" + uname + ":" + pword + "@" + server + "/" + dbname + "?driver=SQL+Server"
```

Update (July 2021) – As above, just modernized (Python 3.6+):

```
f"mssql+pyodbc://{uname}:{pword}@{server}:{port}/{dbname}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

Note that `driver=` must be all lowercase.

Comment: This works better than switching explicitly to `pymssql`

Comment: I used all methods to connect but unsuccessful until I used "?driver=SQL+Server" at the end of the connection string. Thank you for your contribution. It will be great if you can explain why does it failed when we don't use the specific end string you mentioned.

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks muchly

Comment: I am using python 3.7 on a windows machine with SQLAlchemy==1.3.13. I found that ```...driver=SQL+Server``` worked, but ```...driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server``` did not.

Answer (score 4):

Very late, but experienced the same such problem myself recently. Turned out it was a problem with the latest SQLAlchemy version. Had to rollback my version from 1.4.17 to 1.4.12 (unsure of in-between versions, just went with a version I knew worked).

```
pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.12
```

Comment: Good catch, thank you. It shows up with version 1.4.16. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6727) to document this.

Answer (score 0):

I had original poster's problem with a trusted connection to the Microsoft SQL Server database (pandas 1.5.3, SQLAlchemy 2.0.4). Using answers from this question, this did the trick for me:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

server = "servername"
database = "dbname"
driver = "ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
url = f"mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={driver}"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
    
query = """
    SELECT [column1]
    ,[column2] as some_other_name
    FROM [server].[dbo].[table]"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    sqla_query = sqlalchemy.text(query)
    df = pd.read_sql(sqla_query, conn)
```

It should be noted that pandas is not yet fully compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.3.html